# Sorting in R by two columns

Tags: r

I'm trying to sort using two columns in R. This is my code.

```
options(max.print=1000000)
data <- read.table("u.data",header=TRUE)
data<-data[,-4]
data<-data[order(user,movie),]
```

I'm getting the following error -
Error in order(user) : object 'user' not found

A 10 row view of my table is as follows

```
> data[1:10,]
   user movie rate
1   196   242    3
2   186   302    3
3    22   377    1
4   244    51    2
5   166   346    1
6   298   474    4
7   115   265    2
8   253   465    5
9   305   451    3
10    6    86    3
```

Comment: Try `data[with(data, order(user,movie)),]`

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
data<-data[with(data,order(user,movie)),]
```

Or,

```
data<-data[order(data$user,data$movie),]
```